# (How) Can I query classes "post-build", using reflection in C#.Net?

Tags: c#, reflection, runtime, build-process

Scenario:

- I have a list of .cs files in a visual studio project (e.g., MyPOCOs), housing a bunch of POCOs (Plain Old C# Objects)
- I have to run a custom serialization tool (homegrown and I have access to source code) that converts these POCOs into XML files - the tool does this via reflection.

Currently, MyPOCOs project is marked as a *Console App* and has a main method like the one below:

```
class Program
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Initialize custom XML Serializer
            GenerateBulkVmXML batchSerializer = new GenerateBulkVmXML();

            //Add individual POCOs to Serializer
            batchSerializer.AddPocoModel(typeof(MyPOCO1), "My.Custom.NameSpace");
            batchSerializer.AddPocoModel(typeof(MyPOCO2), "My.Custom.NameSpace1");
            batchSerializer.AddPocoModel(typeof(MyPOCO3), "My.Custom.NameSpace2");

            //Generate custom XML
            batchSerializer .WriteXML(); 
        }
}
```

Everytime we "run" the above console app, it triggers the `Main` method, that queries the POCO classes via reflection and spews out the XML.

**Problem:** For every new POCO added to the project, we have add a line to the above `Main` method calling the `batchSerializer.AddPocoModel(...)` method by passing they type of the newly created POCO. Overtime, the number of POCOs will increase and this well get rather unwieldy.

**Proposed Solution:** My team suggests we integrate this process with the "build" of the MyPOCO project, but I'm not sure everyone can grasp the viability of this approach. So, when we 'build' the project in visual studio, the above `Main` method gets executed, in essence. Here are the two problems I see with this approach:

1. *How* can I discover the classes to serialize? Currently I add them to the main method via the `AddPocoModel` method. But if I don't do that, how can I discover them and query them via reflection?
2. *How* exactly do I *trigger* the above main method post-build (i.e., it could be any method in a custom class. I'm just using the `Main` for the sake of argument. Basically, how can I trigger *the* method that does what the main method does above)?

How do I achieve this? Or, is there a better solution to the above problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would break out your serializer into a separate project, a console application would be just fine. This application should take an argument pointing to the DLL that was just compiled, you can then create a post-build command that runs this tool and passes in the DLL name. On the plus side, this creates a reusable tool for other projects. There are a number of macros, but yours would end up looking something like:

`"c:\path\to\serialization\tool.exe" $(TargetPath)`

As for discovering the types, since there is probably nothing differentiating your POCO model classes from other classes (if there are other classes in the DLL), so you will need to mark them somehow. I'd go with a custom attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false)]
public class SerializePOCOAttribute : Attribute { }
```

Then you can use a discovery method for enumerating all the classes in the DLL and serializing them, something like:

```
public class POCOSerializer
{
    public static void Serialize(string dllFileName, GenerateBulkVmXML batchSerializer)
    {
        var assem = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllFileName);

        var pocoObjects = assem.GetTypes().Where(t => t.GetCustomAttribute<SerializePOCOAttribute>() != null);

        foreach (var poco in pocoObjects)
        {
            batchSerializer.AddPocoModel(poco, poco.Namespace);
        }

        batchSerializer.WriteXML();
    }
}
```

Comment: I really like this approach and I'm inclined to go with this. I'm hoping *the build team* doesn't shoot this down, since all projects currently are *not* console apps but class libraries. If console app is not an option, do you have other ideas? Just a thought :) (PS: Currently the POCOs *are* annotated with a custom attribute, so that's a plus :)

Comment: Arbitrary code really isn't "runnable" without something to load it and run. Thats basically what happens when you create an exe project, the compiler adds the appropriate entry points and jumps. You could create a tool that runs the "main" method but you can't just tell the post-build action to run some method in a DLL. I'd have a big problem with a build team that didn't allow some kind of custom tooling, and [dog fooding isn't a bad thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food).

Comment: Where exactly will that post-build event be written? The `.csproj` file of the project for which I want to trigger the tool? That's my current gap in understanding the implementation of this approach - From what I understand are you talking about the pre/post build events that you can configure using Visual Studio's WYSIWYG editor (Project > Properties > Build Events)?

Comment: That is correct, and the build actions end up in the .csproj files. The WYSIWYG is one way to edit them, but if you are using a different build system there are other ways to run post-build actions depending on the build tool.

Comment: A case that I almost forgot about: These classes which are being serialized have certain references to types that live in "another" Project under the same solution. How can this be handled if it's a command-line app? By having appropriate build dependencies/order setup in VS or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Yes, as long as the DLL is referenced by the one you are reflecting, it should be able to load it if necessary. The console application doesn't need a reference to the DLL you are serializing, or any of its dependencies, as long as the dependencies for the DLL are discoverable at load time.

Comment: Unfortunately I keep getting a `ReflectionTypeLoadException` as I expected - The serialize method can't seem to get a hold of the assembly